# angular 2 validator ""

Tags: javascript, validation, angular, typescript

In angular2 I've created a custom validator to validate the value agains a regex.
I know there is a build in one, but I'm facing errors and want to know what's going wrong.

I'm getting this error:

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'.
>   Current value: 'false'.

this is my validator:

```
import { FormControl,Validator,AbstractControl,ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export const PatternValidator = (regex:any):ValidatorFn  => {

  return (control:AbstractControl):{[key: string]: any} => {

    var patt = new RegExp(regex);
    if(!patt.test(control.value)){
      return {
        valid: {valid:false}
      };
    }
    return null;
  };
};
```

in this case it's an regex. But I also tried it with simple string comparion with the same error-result.

this is one of my fields I want to validate:

```
 <div *ngIf="Parameter.Type=='xyz'">
        <input class="form-control" [id]="FieldId" type="text" formControlName="{{FieldId}}" />
    </div>
```

and this is how I set the validator:

```
ngOnInit(){
         this.InitField(); //need to set id in oninit
         this.ValidationForm.addControl(this.FieldId,new FormControl(this.myValue,Validators.compose([Validators.required,CustomValidators.PatternValidator("^[a-zA-Z]?$")])));
    }
```

The error only occurs if the initial value (here this.myValue) is invalid on Startup. If it is valid and I make the value invalid through changing the input-field-value, the validator works just fine...

Comment: Where do you set the pattern? `PatternValidator` is a factory function and should be configured, e.g. `CustomValidators.PatternValidator('a-z')`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just added some example-code and forgot to call the validator properly. I just edited my first post.